# How to lookup values from code and make some new columns based on it

Tags: r, match, lookup

I want to lookup value from a database and make some new columns in a file
actually I have a file like this

```
promo code item stok
sale1  100   a   200
sale2  101   b   300
sale3  102   c   100
sale4  103   d    50
```

and a database looks like this

```
code item1 code_item1 amount_item1 item2 code_item2 amount_item2 
100   a1     1001          2        a2     1002          1
102   a2     1002          1        a3     1003          1
```

and then I want to add my first file several columns which are taken from the database

```
promo code item stok item1 code_item1 amount_item1 item2 code_item2 amount_item2
sale1  100   a   200   a1     1001          400        a2     1002          200
sale2  101   b   300
sale3  102   c   100   a2     1002          100        a3     1003          100
sale4  103   d    50
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `dplyr` is good option, however I such cases always use `merge()`.

```
my_df <- data.frame(promo = c("sale1", "sale2", "sale3", "sale4"), code = c(100, 101, 102, 103), item = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), stok = c(200, 300, 100, 50))
db_df <- data.frame(code = c(100, 102), item1 = c("a1", "a2"), code_item1 = c(1001, 1002), amount_item1 = c(2,1), item2 = c("a2", "a3"), code_item2 = c(1002, 1003), amount_item2 = c(1,1))

result <- merge(x=my_df, y=db_df, by='code', all.x = TRUE)

> result
  code promo item stok item1 code_item1 amount_item1 item2 code_item2 amount_item2
1  100 sale1    a  200    a1       1001            2    a2       1002            1
2  101 sale2    b  300  <NA>         NA           NA  <NA>         NA           NA
3  102 sale3    c  100    a2       1002            1    a3       1003            1
4  103 sale4    d   50  <NA>         NA           NA  <NA>         NA           NA
```

Comment: thanx @Adamm for your answer. I forgot to do some update on my question yesterday. I would like to automatically times each "amount of item" with "stok" first before it filled in the new merged table. What should be modify in the script? thanx so much.

Comment: Could you Modify the question with desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_join()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df <- data.frame(promo = c("sale1", "sale2", "sale3", "sale4"), code = c(100, 101, 102, 103), item = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), stok = c(200, 300, 100, 50))
db_df <- data.frame(code = c(100, 102), item1 = c("a1", "a2"), code_item1 = c(1001, 1002), amount_item1 = c(2,1), item2 = c("a2", "a3"), code_item2 = c(1002, 1003), amount_item2 = c(1,1))

result_df <- left_join(my_df, db_df, by = c("code" = "code"))
result_df

  promo code item stok item1 code_item1 amount_item1 item2 code_item2 amount_item2
1 sale1  100    a  200    a1       1001            2    a2       1002            1
2 sale2  101    b  300  <NA>         NA           NA  <NA>         NA           NA
3 sale3  102    c  100    a2       1002            1    a3       1003            1
4 sale4  103    d   50  <NA>         NA           NA  <NA>         NA           NA
>
```

EDIT: Related to your comment, you can do the multiplying after the left_join as well, there is no need to do it before:

```
result_df$amount_item1 <- result_df$amount_item1 * result_df$stok
result_df$amount_item2 <- result_df$amount_item2 * result_df$stok
```

Comment: thanx @sven for your answer. I forgot to do some update on my question yesterday. I would like to automatically times each "amount of item" with "stok" first before it filled in the new merged table. What should be modify in the script? thanx so much.